# Find the sum of array elements recursively

Tags: java, recursion

i have the following school assignment:
public static  double sum(double [] a, int low, int high)

that returns the sum of all numbers in the array slice a[low:high].

If low > high, it throws an IllegalArgumentException. Otherwise, it checks if
the slice has 1 item. If so, it returns that value.

If the slice has 2 or more items, it divides the slice into 2 equal subslices, computes the sums
of the 2 subslices and returns the sum of the 2 partial sums.
This is what i wrotte:
Iam really bad with recursion, and this is like the first recursive code i writte.

```
public static  double sum(double [] a, int low, int high) throws Exception{
    if(low > high){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    else if(low == high){
        return a[low];  
    }   
    return sum(a, low, high/2) + sum(a, high/2, high);
}
```

how far am i from an answer?
UPDATE:
This is all the code iam executing:

```
public class ArraySum {
    int low; 
    int high;
    double []list;


    public ArraySum(int lowIn, int highIn, double []listIn){
        low = lowIn;
        high = highIn;
        list = listIn;  
    }
    public double auxSum() throws Exception{
        return sum(list, low, high);
    }
    public static  double sum(double [] a, int low, int high) throws Exception{
        if(low > high){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        else if(low == high){
            return a[low];  
        }   
        return sum(a, low, (high+low)/2) + sum(a, (high+(low+1))/2, high);
    }
}
```

and this is my Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        double [] l = {1,2,3,4,5};
        ArraySum a = new ArraySum(0, 5, l);
        System.out.println("the sum is: " + a.auxSum());

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, did you try running what you wrote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it! Here are a few pointers:

- `high/2` isn't really right. (Think about what happens if you have `low` = 98 and `high` = 100.)
- When you recurse you need to keep in mind that the indexes you pass are *inclusive*, so in the second recursive call I suggest you add 1 to the lower index (so that it doesn't overlap with the upper index of the first recursive call)

Let me know if you want me to clarify either item.

Comment: Thanks for the repply, is this what you meant?                       return sum(a, low, (high+low)/2) + sum(a, (high+(low+1))/2, high);

Comment: You got the first one right. `(high+low)/2`. Now just append `+1` to that for the second one :-)

Comment: the thing is that the method does not return, it gives me an error.

Comment: @CarlosLuis Also, as a separate issue, you don't need to write `throws Exception`. You don't have to declare that a method can throw an `IllegalArgumentException` as it is not a checked exception.

Comment: @CarlosLuis, at this point you're close enough. Take a peek [here](http://ideone.com/weWBNs).

Comment: Iam getting an array out of bounds exeption.

Comment: yep. you are. max index in a 5 element array is 4.

Comment: Yes i was, the array had five elements yet i started the algorithm with 0 as lower bound and 5 as upper bound, that made the program crash, i corrected it to 0 and 4 and now works like a charm, thanks for the help and the time you put into this.