# I need to get the largest number in an array recursively

Tags: java, arrays

I was trying to find the largest in array of doubles but, the hard part is that you have to divide the array in two slices which I did, but after that you need to compute the largest values of the 2 sub slices and return the largest of the 2 values, and it needs to be using recursion.

Can you give me a tip in how to start please.

```
public static  double getLargest(double [] a, int low, int high)
    {
       int c =  (low+high)/2; 
       double slice1[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, low,c + 1 ); 
       double slice2[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(a,c , high+1);
       if(low > high || high > a.length-1 ||low < 0 )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
       if(low == high )
            return a[low];
       else{ 

      }   
    }  
  }
```

Comment: i dont have any idea how to begin, i been the whole day trying to solve this problem

Comment: I don't see any recursion in the posted code.

Comment: This is conceptually very close to this, maybe you can get inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932314/find-the-sum-of-array-elements-recursively?rq=1

Comment: I would suggest that you don't copy the array. Instead just pass the bounds as indices to the method.

Comment: @Thilo Yes both questions are conspicuously similar, with identical variable names and similar whitespace peculiarities.  Both users are of the same ethnicity too.  Two students from the same high school asking homework questions? :)

Comment: Im not in high school, we dont have anything to do @JoeCoder

Comment: That question was asked 7 months ago, is very similar but not the same

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask yourself what to do in that `else` part.

You are now faced with an array of two or more elements.

You could say:

- find the maximum of the first half of that array (by calling the same method again, i.e. recursion, but with a "shorter" input array)
- find the maximum of the second half of that array
- return the bigger of these two results